# Any way to fold uncertainties/weights into scikit-learn validation_curve?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a time series dataset that includes uncertainties on each point. I want to use [sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html) to figure out the best value of my hyperparameter, gamma, for a [sklearn.svm.svr()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) (support vector machine regression). It is simple to pass in the uncertainties (actually their inverse, sample_weights) to the svr().fit() function, which works great. None of the inputs for validation_curve() seem to allow this though. Is there a workaround?

```
# Create some fake data
times = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)[:, None]
data = np.sin(times).ravel()
uncertainty = np.linspace(0.05, 0.1, num=10)
np.random.shuffle(uncertainty)
sample_weight = 1 / uncertainty


# Quick helper function
def jpm_svr(gamma=1e-6, **kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=gamma, **kwargs))

# Find the best value of gamma
gamma = np.logspace(-2, 5, num=11, base=10)
shuffle_split = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=20, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5, random_state=None)
######## The next line is where I want to input the sample_weight but can't
train_score, val_score = validation_curve(jpm_svr(), X, y, #sample_weight :(
                                          'svr__gamma',
                                          gamma, cv=shuffle_split, scoring=evs)
score = np.median(val_score, axis=1)
best_score_index = np.argmax(score)

# Generate model with best value of gamma and plot it over the data
# Also note that I can now pass in sample_weight
model = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=gamma[best_score_index]).fit(times, data, sample_weight)
X_test = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)[:, None]
y_test = model.predict(X_test)
plt.errorbar(times, data, yerr=uncertainty, fmt='o');
plt.plot(X_test.ravel(), y_test, linewidth=6);
```

[image]